Proper usage of externalizing tikz/standalone with Overleaf
I've attempted to set up Tikz externalization to speed up how fast the compile time is on an Overleaf project I have. I followed the answers provided on the SE question How to externalize TikZ pictures. I have an MWE to demonstrate my problem. I have a basic set of tex files where the main file test0.tex tries to load the images produced using Tikz in the other three files test1.tex, test2.tex, and test3.tex. This is what I have written
%%%%%%%% test0.tex %%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Pre-Load Packages Order %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew,group=true,subpreambles=false]{standalone} % For side loaded Tikz Figures
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx} % for Figures
\usepackage{pgfplots} % For plotting
\usepackage{tikz} % For the background and plotting
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\title{TBD}
\author{Boaty McBoatface}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\let\newpage\relax%
\maketitle
\endgroup

\begin{figure}[h]\centering
    \begin{minipage}{4in}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[trim={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt},clip,width=0.55\textwidth]{test1.pdf}
    \end{minipage}
    
    \begin{minipage}{4in}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[trim={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt},clip,width=0.55\textwidth]{test2.pdf}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}{4in}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[trim={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt},clip,width=0.55\textwidth]{test3.pdf}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}


\end{document}

%%%%%%%% test1.tex %%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[margin=10pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every axis/.append style={width=0.5\linewidth,title style={align=center}}]
\begin{axis}
     \addplot coordinates { (1,2) (2,3) (3,0)};
\end{axis}
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-1,-13.4) -- (21.25,-13.4);
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-1,-13.4) -- (-1,3.7);
\node[below, yshift=-5mm] at (10.375,-13.4) {{\huge $Y$}};
\node[left, xshift=-1cm, rotate=90] at (-1,-3.9) {{\huge $X$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,1.81) -- (-1,1.81)     node[left]  {{\LARGE$5$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-2.35) -- (-1,-2.35)   node[left]  {{\LARGE $3.4$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-6.51) -- (-1,-6.51)   node[left]  {{\LARGE $1.7$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-10.67) -- (-1,-10.67) node[left]  {{\LARGE $0.1$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (2.19, -13.15) -- (2.19,-13.4) node[below]     {{\LARGE $0$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (7.79, -13.15) -- (7.79,-13.4) node[below]   {{\LARGE $1$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (13.34,-13.15) -- (13.34,-13.4) node[below]   {{\LARGE $2$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (18.89,-13.15) -- (18.89,-13.4) node[below] {{\LARGE $3$}};
\node[] at (10.375,4.5) {{\Huge Title \#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

%%%%%%% test2.text %%%%%%%
\documentclass[margin=10pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every axis/.append style={width=0.5\linewidth,title style={align=center}}]
\begin{axis}
     \addplot coordinates { (-1,-1) (1,0) (-2,3)};
\end{axis}
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-1,-13.4) -- (21.25,-13.4);
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-1,-13.4) -- (-1,3.7);
\node[below, yshift=-5mm] at (10.375,-13.4) {{\huge $Y$}};
\node[left, xshift=-1cm, rotate=90] at (-1,-3.9) {{\huge $X$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,1.81) -- (-1,1.81)     node[left]  {{\LARGE$5$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-2.35) -- (-1,-2.35)   node[left]  {{\LARGE $3.4$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-6.51) -- (-1,-6.51)   node[left]  {{\LARGE $1.7$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-10.67) -- (-1,-10.67) node[left]  {{\LARGE $0.1$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (2.19, -13.15) -- (2.19,-13.4) node[below]     {{\LARGE $0$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (7.79, -13.15) -- (7.79,-13.4) node[below]   {{\LARGE $1$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (13.34,-13.15) -- (13.34,-13.4) node[below]   {{\LARGE $2$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (18.89,-13.15) -- (18.89,-13.4) node[below] {{\LARGE $3$}};
\node[] at (10.375,4.5) {{\Huge Title \#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

%%%%%%% test3.tex %%%%%%%
\documentclass[margin=10pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every axis/.append style={width=0.5\linewidth,title style={align=center}}]
\begin{axis}
     \addplot coordinates { (1,1) (2,4) (-3,6)};
\end{axis}
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-1,-13.4) -- (21.25,-13.4);
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-1,-13.4) -- (-1,3.7);
\node[below, yshift=-5mm] at (10.375,-13.4) {{\huge $Y$}};
\node[left, xshift=-1cm, rotate=90] at (-1,-3.9) {{\huge $X$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,1.81) -- (-1,1.81)     node[left]  {{\LARGE$5$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-2.35) -- (-1,-2.35)   node[left]  {{\LARGE $3.4$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-6.51) -- (-1,-6.51)   node[left]  {{\LARGE $1.7$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-10.67) -- (-1,-10.67) node[left]  {{\LARGE $0.1$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (2.19, -13.15) -- (2.19,-13.4) node[below]     {{\LARGE $0$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (7.79, -13.15) -- (7.79,-13.4) node[below]   {{\LARGE $1$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (13.34,-13.15) -- (13.34,-13.4) node[below]   {{\LARGE $2$}};
\draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (18.89,-13.15) -- (18.89,-13.4) node[below] {{\LARGE $3$}};
\node[] at (10.375,4.5) {{\Huge Title \#3}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

When I run test0.tex from scratch I get:

Now if I then change the lines in test0.tex from \includegraphics[trim={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt},clip,width=0.55\textwidth]{test1.pdf} to \includestandalone[trim={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt},clip,width=0.55\textwidth]{test1} (same for the other two) the images do load!

However, they load slower (at least they do in the actual project I'm using which has quite hefty figures). However, I can change back to the original lines that call \includegraphics and I get the same result only much faster. The question I'm ultimately getting at is: Can there be a way that I can have my images load in faster (at the very least when recompiling) than using \includestandalone without me having to re-edit the file each time I compile from scratch?
EDIT: A possible solution based on David's answer would be to delete the hidden pdf whenever the standalone file is recompiled. If anyone knows if files can be deleted via a command written in the .tex file, I think this would fully solve my issue.

not directly related but you could replace each \begin{minipage}{4in}         \centering         \includegraphics[trim={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt},clip,width=0.55\textwidth]{test1.pdf}     \end{minipage} by just \includegraphics[width=2.2in]{test1.pdf}  as minipage, centering and trim are doing nothing here

A very good point, I should have removed those for the MWE. I generally keep those in so I can remember the syntax for cropping figures.

That comes at a price though, You and I might know they do nothing, but latex doesn't. it goes through all the motions of setting up a clipping path and adding clip operators to the pdf. even though it has no visible effect.

memoize is significantly faster than the external library, especially when compiling the externals is required, and can compile material the library can't. Unlike external, it doesn't need a separate run per picture.

Is far as I can tell you want something like
\IfFileExists{file.pdf}
  {\includegraphics[...]{file.pdf}}
  {\includestandalone[...]{file.pdf}}


There's an extra opening brace on the third line. And I'm not sure you want the extension.

@cfr brace gone thanks, I think you should use an extension here as you know what file format is going to be built do you may as well just look for that, no point in looping over all graphics extensions hoping an .eps will appear from somewhere.

@cfr but probably memoize is better anyway if you want to post an answer...

Ah. I didn't think of it like that. I don't usually use \includestandalone but just \file_input:n or \input.

@cfr I've never used it:-)

I expect you write code which works first time.

@cfr so naive:-)

The issue with this approach is if you update the tex file that produces the image, the new image won't show up as the conditional will still be using includesgraphic

yes you could add additional test on \pdffilemoddate of the pdf and the tex source @DavidG.

Is there a way for me to store the previous modification datetime so I can compare?

if you put the tex source of each figure in a separate tex file that you \input you could check the file modification date of that against the pdf. @DavidG.

Isn't this precisely why people wrote external, memoize and robust-externalize?

@cfr yes I would guess so.

@cfr The issue is that memoize and robost-externalize are not available yet on Overleaf. As for external I have yet to find a way to use this AND separate the tikz figures in another file where I can compile and adjust them on their own.

@DavidCarlisle Do you think you could include the necessary lines that allow for that dynamic verification? I've been trying to implement it on Overleaf but I have yet to figure out to achieve this

You can use the external library with standalone and \input, but I don't know if that is faster than \includestandalone. I didn't realise Overleaf didn't yet have TL 2024.

I did have a personal solution detailed in the first answer here: How to externalize TikZ pictures, however, I couldn't compile/adjust the figure on its own before incorporating it into the main document. The second answer from that link is what I was doing but that takes too long to compile because my figures are so intricate

memoize is significantly faster than the external library and can externalise material the library can't. It is also more secure as there is no need to enable shell escape, at least if you use TeX Live.
To use this, remove the buildnew from standalone and ensure you don't specify a file extension when calling \includestandalone. The external images will be produced during the first compilation as additional pages in your PDF. During the second, they are extracted and included. memoize will rebuild them if the content of tikzpicture changes. All of this is configurable.
By default, perl is used to extract the externs. The python option is a bit faster, if that's an option. In either case, you may need to install a library to get things set up. Either consult memoize's documentation or take a look at the brief introduction I wrote as an answer here (which I'll try to find when I've finished this).
I've left the trimming etc. in place, even though it will also slow compilation.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-t1.tex}
\documentclass[margin=10pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every axis/.append style={width=0.5\linewidth,title style={align=center}}]
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates { (1,2) (2,3) (3,0)};
  \end{axis}
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-1,-13.4) -- (21.25,-13.4);
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-1,-13.4) -- (-1,3.7);
  \node[below, yshift=-5mm] at (10.375,-13.4) {{\huge $Y$}};
  \node[left, xshift=-1cm, rotate=90] at (-1,-3.9) {{\huge $X$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,1.81) -- (-1,1.81)     node[left]  {{\LARGE$5$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-2.35) -- (-1,-2.35)   node[left]  {{\LARGE $3.4$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-6.51) -- (-1,-6.51)   node[left]  {{\LARGE $1.7$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-10.67) -- (-1,-10.67) node[left]  {{\LARGE $0.1$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (2.19, -13.15) -- (2.19,-13.4) node[below]     {{\LARGE $0$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (7.79, -13.15) -- (7.79,-13.4) node[below]   {{\LARGE $1$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (13.34,-13.15) -- (13.34,-13.4) node[below]   {{\LARGE $2$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (18.89,-13.15) -- (18.89,-13.4) node[below] {{\LARGE $3$}};
  \node[] at (10.375,4.5) {{\Huge Title \#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-t2.tex}
\documentclass[margin=10pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every axis/.append style={width=0.5\linewidth,title style={align=center}}]
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates { (-1,-1) (1,0) (-2,3)};
  \end{axis}
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-1,-13.4) -- (21.25,-13.4);
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-1,-13.4) -- (-1,3.7);
  \node[below, yshift=-5mm] at (10.375,-13.4) {{\huge $Y$}};
  \node[left, xshift=-1cm, rotate=90] at (-1,-3.9) {{\huge $X$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,1.81) -- (-1,1.81)     node[left]  {{\LARGE$5$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-2.35) -- (-1,-2.35)   node[left]  {{\LARGE $3.4$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-6.51) -- (-1,-6.51)   node[left]  {{\LARGE $1.7$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-10.67) -- (-1,-10.67) node[left]  {{\LARGE $0.1$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (2.19, -13.15) -- (2.19,-13.4) node[below]     {{\LARGE $0$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (7.79, -13.15) -- (7.79,-13.4) node[below]   {{\LARGE $1$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (13.34,-13.15) -- (13.34,-13.4) node[below]   {{\LARGE $2$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (18.89,-13.15) -- (18.89,-13.4) node[below] {{\LARGE $3$}};
  \node[] at (10.375,4.5) {{\Huge Title \#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-t3.tex}
\documentclass[margin=10pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every axis/.append style={width=0.5\linewidth,title style={align=center}}]
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates { (1,1) (2,4) (-3,6)};
  \end{axis}
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-1,-13.4) -- (21.25,-13.4);
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-1,-13.4) -- (-1,3.7);
  \node[below, yshift=-5mm] at (10.375,-13.4) {{\huge $Y$}};
  \node[left, xshift=-1cm, rotate=90] at (-1,-3.9) {{\huge $X$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,1.81) -- (-1,1.81)     node[left]  {{\LARGE$5$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-2.35) -- (-1,-2.35)   node[left]  {{\LARGE $3.4$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-6.51) -- (-1,-6.51)   node[left]  {{\LARGE $1.7$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (-0.75,-10.67) -- (-1,-10.67) node[left]  {{\LARGE $0.1$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (2.19, -13.15) -- (2.19,-13.4) node[below]     {{\LARGE $0$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (7.79, -13.15) -- (7.79,-13.4) node[below]   {{\LARGE $1$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (13.34,-13.15) -- (13.34,-13.4) node[below]   {{\LARGE $2$}};
  \draw[-,line width=0.25mm] (18.89,-13.15) -- (18.89,-13.4) node[below] {{\LARGE $3$}};
  \node[] at (10.375,4.5) {{\Huge Title \#3}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{memoize}
\mmzset{%
  prefix=memos/,
}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[group=true,subpreambles=false]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\title{TBD}
\author{Boaty McBoatface}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\let\newpage\relax%
\maketitle
\endgroup

\begin{figure}[h]\centering
  \begin{minipage}{4in}
    \centering
%     \includegraphics[trim={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt},clip,width=0.55\textwidth]{test1.pdf}
    \includestandalone[trim={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt},clip,width=0.55\textwidth]{\jobname-t1}
  \end{minipage}
  
  \begin{minipage}{4in}
    \centering
%     \includegraphics[trim={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt},clip,width=0.55\textwidth]{test2.pdf}
    \includestandalone[trim={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt},clip,width=0.55\textwidth]{\jobname-t2}
  \end{minipage}
  
  \begin{minipage}{4in}
    \centering
%     \includegraphics[trim={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt},clip,width=0.55\textwidth]{test3.pdf}
    \includestandalone[trim={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt},clip,width=0.55\textwidth]{\jobname-t2}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

